# Expand div around children elements (no wrapper)

Tags: javascript, html, css

From what I've seen this isn't possible w/o javascript. I have a series of images that are inside of a parent div. The images are pretty much limited to one size. I want the parent div to expand or shrink with the images. Right now it cuts off the images - I think because overflow:hidden;

this is the ID if you look with firebug:

```
<div id="zt-container" class="zt-container">

<http://www.zakweinberg.com/imagezoomtour>
```

I've tried percents and removing the height div.

CSS is the best. If not, I'm open to javascript.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Kishore I mean the white div around the image. It doesn't expand the way I've tried to explain. Think of a Jquery image slide that expands to fit both horizontal and vertical images. If you click the white box on my examples, it pulls the next images but cuts shows only what fits inside the parent div. 

Hope I've clarified a bit... 

RobG - My limited scope of "appropriate CSS" knowledge is why I'm here.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `img.zt-current` elements are `position:absolute`, your `.zt-item` divs are 0 height. On top of this, you have `height: 450px` on the `.zt-container` div. If you take off the absolute positioning on the images, and the fixed height on the container, the container will expand to fit the images. The problem is that it expands to show the images when they do their animated transition, which you probably don't want.

You'll probably have to change the height of the `.zt-container` div using javascript if you want to keep the animated transitions. Get the height of the image, and use it to set the height of the container. Something like:

```
$('.zt-container').animate({
    height: $('img.zt-current').height()
});
```

This looks similar to what you want: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/

Comment: Tom, I never got around to testing this out due to an exquisite brew of incompetence and laziness). I went ahead and gave each img 100% width and height attributes to fill out the container. Thanks for the help. 

http://www.zakweinberg.com/imagezoomtour

Answer (score 0):

I checked the link in mozilla.
The problem is only with 2nd image.

Add width:100% to your images and this will fit into the div.

Comment: Rain - Good idea, but that sizes the photo to the div. What I'm trying to accomplish is make the outer div shrink or expand to fit the inner content - without compromising the inner photos.

Comment: In that case removing the hard coded width value for your div and make it center aligned.

Comment: Rain,

Your solution was ultimately what I did - Thanks.

http://www.zakweinberg.com/imagezoomtour